# creating a nested list class within python

Tags: python

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have to create a nested list(of possible solutions to a problem), so I created a class that appends a solution to a list of existing solutions(since each solution is being calculated one at a time)

This function works fine:

```
def appendList(list):
    #print list
    list2.append(list)

x =0
while x < 10:
    x = x+1
    one = "one"
    two = "two"
    appendList([(one), (two)])

print list2
```

with a result of:

```
[['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two']]
```

but when I take this exact same function and put it in a class, I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: appendList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's the class and how I call it:

> ```
> class SolutionsAppendList:
>     list2 = []
>     def appendList(list):
>     #print list
>         list2.append(list)
> ```

```
appendList.appendList([('one'), ('two')])
```

I'm sure I'm making a very basic error but I can't seem to figure out why, since I'm using the same function in the class.

Any suggestions/advice would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with classes here, it's important to use `instance variables`. These can be accessed by using the `self` keyword. And if you're dealing with class methods, be sure to make their first argument `self`. So, modified...

```
class SolutionsAppendList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def appendList(self, list):
    #print list
        self.list.append(list)
```

What's cool about this is that you no longer need `list2`. Instance variables (`self.list`). Are different than local variables (the `list` you pass to the `appendList()` method). EDIT: I"ve also added an `__init__` method, which is called once an instance of the `SolutionsAppendList` object is created. In my first reply, I overlooked the fact that `self.*` is not available outside of a method. This is the edited code (Thanks David).

Comment: `self` isn't defined outside of a method, so `self.list = []` won't work here. That statement should actually be put in `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I like your solution.  I am going to keep adding lists to this and when I want to access it I simply type 'print appendList.list'  does that work? or is there a better way to access the list I am appending to?

Comment: @Lostsoul, I'm not sure why you would print appendList.list, unless appendList happens to be the variable you use to store a SolutionsAppendList? Essentially, inside the class you can call self.list, and outside of the class, you can call OBJECT.list, where `OBJECT` denotes the instance of `SolutionsAppendList`.

Comment: @JordanScales not really to print(just using it as an example).  I want to use this class to capture solutions as I make them, and then be able to refer to them later.  Seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

When working with a class instance the special variable `self` is always passed as the first argument to the method calls.  You need to modify your function declaration to accommodate this:

```
class SolutionList:
  def appendList(self, list):
    #rest of your function here.
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
class SolutionsAppendList:
    list2 = []
    def appendList(self, list):
    #print list
        self.list2.append(list)
```

Class methods should always have self (reference to instance) as the first parameter.